# Meta analysis Hazard Ratio with small number of studies (n=2)

Tags: meta-analysis, hazard

I am doing a fixed effect meta-analysis pooling hazard ratios from 2 very similar cohorts.
I understand that the **inverse variance method** is most commonly used to pool HR, however I also read that this method tends to be biased when meta-analysing a small number of studies (<5) and in that case the **Peto or Mantel-Haenszel methods** tend to perform better.
Could someone please recommend an unbiased method for meta-analysis of a small number of time to event data?

Also should the **modified Hartung-Knapp confidence intervals** be reported here?

Comment: If the data are provided by a randomized trial, you can use incidence rate ratios, extracting events, patients at risk, and follow-up duration for each study arm with metainc: https://rdrr.io/cran/meta/man/metainc.html

Comment: I think both Peto and M-H rely on having a binary outcome with frequencies which I assume you do not have if you only have HR.